# fortran compiler 4 vs 11

Tags: fortran

I am porting an application from fortran older version (4.0) to new version (11.0). While porting I am facing some problems with real*4 variables:

```
real*4 a,b,c

a=0.9876875
b=0.6754345

c=a*b
```

value for `c` in old compiler `0.667118`, which is correct value. But with new compiler I am getting a small variation from the output(c variable) like `0.667120`. Though it is a small variation, I am using these values in some other calculation. So the overall output has a huge difference. How to overcome this issue?

Comment: What Fortran compiler are you using?

Comment: Reiterating Pillsy's question. AFAIK Fortran 4 is the name of the language pre- Fortran 66. The best reference I could find for "Fotran 11" are specific compiler versions from Abisoft and Intel. You need to be more specific.

Comment: Hmmm. Also, does the CPU happen to be x86 compatable (Intel/AMD PC)? That makes a difference for floating-point.

Comment: @T.E.D - I presume you mean, Absoft Pro Fortran, not Abisoft. As for cvnravi, I think he's not reffering to old fortran IV (very rarely written as "fortran 4"), but the compiler.

Comment: If you are that concerned with precision, you should probably be using `real*8` instead of `real*4` anyway.  With PGI Fortran and GNU Fortran, I've also used the non-IEEE compliant mode (GNU calls this `-ffast-math`, I forget what PGI calls it) to keep the intermediate results in the FPU registers instead of pulling them out and rounding on each operation, which fixed some issues I had along the same lines.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden - if he's concerned about precision, he should define his own presicion range. With real*4 or *8, you still have the uncertainty of how it will be represented on various machines. While, when using your defined type you don't have that problem, since you define your demands, assuming the cpu can represent it. Portable also, since you no longer depend on various representations (real*4 on one compiler/cpu necessarily isn't the same as on the other).

Answer (score 2):

You are, I'm assuming, going from Microsoft Fortran Powerstation 4 to Intel Visual Fortran 11.xx ?

Anyways, try this:

```
program test32

integer, parameter :: iwp = selected_real_kind(15,300)

real(iwp) :: a,b,c

a=0.9876875
b=0.6754345

c=a*b
write(*,'(3f12.8)')a,b,c

end program test32
```

which gives out:

```
0.98768753  0.67543453  0.66711826
```

I will not explain selected_real_kind, not because I do not wish, but because the help will probably do it much better. But, do ask if something in here is not clear.

p.s. The representation of real*4, or any type of real is processor dependent, and compiler dependent and that is one of the reasons why you're getting different results.

Answer (score 2):

Discussion of changes in Intel visual Fortran compiler version 11 here:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/68587/

The upshot is that older versions of the Fortran compiler would implicitly promote single-precision values to double-precision before performing an operation. The default behavior in version 11 is to perform the operation with single-precision. There are compiler options (`/arch:ia32`) to enable the old behavior in the new compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Intel. Try to compile without optimization..